# Enforcing canonical URLs with multiple custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, url-rewriting, request-filter

I'm working on a project with several custom post types, where one of the post types is naturally (but not actually in the WordPress sense) the 'parent' of the others.  For example, say I have a custom post type called 'book' and another one called 'character', and say I want to have the following custom URL structure:

```
books/[book-name]/characters/[character-name]
```

Thus, the canonical URL for the post about the character Thing One in the book The Cat In the Hat would be:

```
 books/cat-in-the-hat/characters/thing-one
```

A character is associated with a book with a post meta row.

I've created custom rewrites to make it work...

```
add_rewrite_rule (
    '^books/([^\/]+)/characters/([^\/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?book=$matches[1]&character=$matches[2]&post_type=character'
);
```

...but I'd also need to make sure that the 'character post' in the URL belongs to the 'book'...

```
books/cat-in-the-hat/characters/thing-one     //good
books/anna-karenina/characters/count-vronsky  //good
books/anna-karenina/characters/thing-one      //bad
```

This can't happen automatically: I have to hook into a filter or an action to check whether the character matches the book, and if not, either redirect to the correct, canonical URL or force a 404.

Where's the best place to accomplish this check?  My choices (so far) are:

- The `request` filter -- i.e. checking before the main query is instantiated.
- The various WP_Query filters -- i.e. make WP_Query do the checking for me by adding a post meta constraint.

I realize this is rather an open-ended question and probably a matter of taste, but any insight into the most code and database efficient way of doing things would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: How do you link the charater to the book internally? via a taxonomy?

Comment: It sounds like @ChrisCarson said `post meta row` which I can only assume when the user creates a new book, they somehow find / pick the character(s) attached to it, which is then saved as meta values attached to the book post ID. That being said, I am confused with OPs final example - the last url being bad assumes that 2 different books cannot have the same character names.

Answer (score 1):

I tackled [subordinate post types](https://github.com/codearachnid/wp-subordinate-post) with a similar vein but was not as strict on the canonical url aspect; however, I ran into a similar situation with deeplinking custom [WooCommerce product type](https://github.com/codearachnid/woocommerce-product-permalink) links.

I leveraged the `template_redirect` hook to push a 404 if it didn't match the route and the `post_type_link` to ensure the meta tag for canonical link and all `the_permalink()` and `get_permalink()` references matched the intended link.

A snippit of the way I would recommend handling this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp20140320_template_redirect' );
public function wp20140320_template_redirect(){
    global $wp_query, $post;

    // the character post type has the book id set as meta?
    // or could set as post_parent if you don't have characters heirarchical
    $book_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_book_id', true );

    // compare_parent_slug_to_id to check required $book_id against set parent book slug
    if( $post->post_type == 'character' && ! compare_parent_slug_to_id( $book_id ) ){

        // set is_404 since post type is character and parent slug does not match set
        $wp_query->is_404 = true;
        status_header(404);
        include get_404_template();
        exit; // maybe a better way to gracefully exit?

    }
}
```

Modified from [source](https://github.com/codearachnid/woocommerce-product-permalink/blob/master/inc/product-type-permalinks.php)